# Gnome terminal eats emacs undo key sequence

Tags: emacs, gnome-terminal

I am running emacs 21 in gnome-terminal with the --nox option. When I press C-_, the font size decreases instead of emacs undoing my previous action. How do I prevent gnome-terminal from eating the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default decreasing the font size is bound to <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> in `gnome-terminal`, so it should not interfere with `emacs`'s undo.

You can cross-check in `gnome-terminal` (*Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts*) if it is bound to <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> instead. Otherwise make sure you press the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key when un-doing in `emacs` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> I think.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl-x u</kbd> is an alternative to undo.

See http://linux.about.com/od/emacs_doc/a/emacsdoc539.htm.